# Error trying to setup policy-based auth in .net CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm following the Microsoft tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1

After I run my API and hit the endpoint I get the error

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
```

However looking at the tutorial there doesn't seem to be any places where they use AddAuthentication

I've noticed that I can avoid the error if I succeed the policy check eg.

```
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumRequirement requirement)
        {
         
            //If I comment this line I get error
            context.Succeed(requirement);
  
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my Startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();//Required for using  IHttpContextAccessor
          
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,MinimumHandler>();
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("MinimumPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumRequirement())));

        }
```

Here is my Handler:

```
    public class MinimumHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumRequirement>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;
        public MinimumHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumRequirement requirement)
        {
         
            //If I uncomment this line everything works fine
           //context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your code of startup class.

Answer (score 0):

AddAuthentication in startup.cs file and also context.Succeed(requirement); this line is the key line for checking policy.